# Relation between a set being closed under a binary operation and the set being a group under that binary operation

Tags: group-theory, elementary-set-theory

If a set $S$ is not closed under some binary operation $\star$, is it true that $S$ cannot be a group under $\star$?

Comment: Did you figure out your dihedral group question? I was writing an answer to it.

Comment: Sorry, yeah I figured it out after staring at $D_8$'s lattice structure for a bit.

Comment: If you're looking at the lattice structure of $D_8$ hosted on a website in order to figure out $D_{2n}/\langle r\rangle$, it may be problematic; it's necessary to be able to figure out what quotient groups are and what their elements look like on your own, especially for basic groups like dihedral ones. [Here](http://i.imgur.com/aw1RoXp.png) is what I was going to write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true.  An operation in a group has to stay within the group.